# iOS app - user defaults using NSUserDefaults, saving on Simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I have an iOS app , that has been saving user defaults using NSUserDefaults, however, all of a sudden , the app is no longer saving defaults on the device , but it works perfectly in the simulator.

Here are the methods I am calling to save settings

```
        -(void)saveSettings{

        defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        settingsData = [defaults objectForKey:(NSString *)@"SettingsKey"];

      settingsDict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:settingsData];

        NSMutableDictionary * settingsMutableDictionary = [settingsDict mutableCopy];

        [settingsMutableDictionary setValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool:_dawnAlarmSwitch.on] forKey: @"dawnAlarmSwitch"];
        [settingsMutableDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:_sunriseAlarmSwitch.on] forKey:  @"sunriseAlarmSwitch"];
        [settingsMutableDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:_noonAlarmSwitch.on] forKey:  @"noonAlarmSwitch"];
        [settingsMutableDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:_afternoonAlarmSwitch.on] forKey:  @"afternoonAlarmSwitch"];
        [settingsMutableDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:_sunsetAlarmSwitch.on] forKey:  @"sunsetAlarmSwitch"];
        [settingsMutableDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:_nightAlarmSwitch.on] forKey:  @"nightAlarmSwitch"];
        [settingsMutableDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_dawnAlarmDelaySlider.value] forKey:  @"dawnAlarmDelaySlider"];
        [settingsMutableDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_noonAlarmDelaySlider.value] forKey:  @"noonAlarmDelaySlider"];
        [settingsMutableDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_afternoonAlarmDelaySlider.value] forKey:  @"afternoonAlarmDelaySlider"];
        [settingsMutableDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_sunsetAlarmDelaySlider.value] forKey:  @"sunsetAlarmDelaySlider"];
        [settingsMutableDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_nightAlarmDelaySlider.value] forKey:  @"nightAlarmDelaySlider"];
        [settingsMutableDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_dawnSnoozeIntervalSlider.value] forKey:  @"dawnSnoozeIntervalSlider"];
        [settingsMutableDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_noonSnoozeIntervalSlider.value] forKey:  @"noonSnoozeIntervalSlider"];
        [settingsMutableDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_afternoonSnoozeIntervalSlider.value] forKey:  @"afternoonSnoozeIntervalSlider"];
        [settingsMutableDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_sunsetSnoozeIntervalSlider.value] forKey:  @"sunsetSnoozeIntervalSlider"];
        [settingsMutableDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_nightSnoozeIntervalSlider.value] forKey:  @"nightSnoozeIntervalSlider"];

       // CFShow((__bridge CFTypeRef)(settingsDict));

        settingsDict = [settingsMutableDictionary copy];

        settingsData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:settingsDict];
        [defaults setObject:settingsData forKey:(NSString *)@"SettingsKey"];
        [defaults synchronize];

        kvStore = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];
        [kvStore setObject:settingsData forKey:(NSString *)@"SettingsKey"];
        [kvStore synchronize];

    }
```

and here is the method for retrieving settings:

```
    -(void)getSettings{

        kvStore = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];

        settingsData = [kvStore objectForKey:(NSString *)@"SettingsKey"];

        if (!settingsData){

            defaults= [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            settingsData = [defaults objectForKey:(NSString *)@"SettingsKey"];

        }


        if (!settingsData)
            [self createSettings];

        if (settingsData){

                settingsDict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:settingsData];
               _showArabicQuranSwitch.on= [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"showArabicQuranSwitch"] boolValue];

                _dawnAlarmSwitch.on= [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"dawnAlarmSwitch"] boolValue];
                _sunriseAlarmSwitch.on= [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"sunriseAlarmSwitch"] boolValue];
                _noonAlarmSwitch.on= [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"noonAlarmSwitch"] boolValue];
                _afternoonAlarmSwitch.on= [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"afternoonAlarmSwitch"] boolValue];
                _sunsetAlarmSwitch.on= [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"sunsetAlarmSwitch"] boolValue];
                _nightAlarmSwitch.on= [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"nightAlarmSwitch"] boolValue];

                _dawnAlarmDelaySlider.value= [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"dawnAlarmDelaySlider"] intValue];
                _noonAlarmDelaySlider.value= [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"noonAlarmDelaySlider"] intValue];
                _afternoonAlarmDelaySlider.value= [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"afternoonAlarmDelaySlider"] intValue];
                _sunsetAlarmDelaySlider.value= [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"sunsetAlarmDelaySlider"] intValue];
                _nightAlarmDelaySlider.value= [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"nightAlarmDelaySlider"] intValue];

                _dawnSnoozeIntervalSlider.value= [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"dawnSnoozeIntervalSlider"] intValue];

                if(self.dawnAlarmDelaySlider.value <0.0f)
                _dawnAlarmDelayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f mins before",  _dawnAlarmDelaySlider.value*-1];
                else
                    _dawnAlarmDelayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f mins after",  _dawnAlarmDelaySlider.value];




                _noonSnoozeIntervalSlider.value= [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"noonSnoozeIntervalSlider"] intValue];

                if(self.noonAlarmDelaySlider.value<0.0f)
                _noonAlarmDelayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f mins before",  _noonAlarmDelaySlider.value*-1];
                else
                     _noonAlarmDelayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f mins after",  _noonAlarmDelaySlider.value];


                _afternoonSnoozeIntervalSlider.value= [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"afternoonSnoozeIntervalSlider"] intValue];

                 if(self.afternoonAlarmDelaySlider.value<0.0f)
                     _afternoonAlarmDelayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f mins before",  _afternoonAlarmDelaySlider.value*-1];
                 else
                _afternoonAlarmDelayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f mins after",  _afternoonAlarmDelaySlider.value];



                _sunsetSnoozeIntervalSlider.value= [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"sunsetSnoozeIntervalSlider"] intValue];

                 if(self.sunsetAlarmDelaySlider.value<0.0f)
                     _sunsetAlarmDelayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f mins before",  _sunsetAlarmDelaySlider.value*-1];
                 else
                _sunsetAlarmDelayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f mins after",  _sunsetAlarmDelaySlider.value];




                _nightSnoozeIntervalSlider.value= [[settingsDict objectForKey:@"nightSnoozeIntervalSlider"] intValue];

                if(self.nightAlarmDelaySlider.value<0.0f)
                    _nightAlarmDelayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f mins before",  _nightAlarmDelaySlider.value*-1];
                else
                   _nightAlarmDelayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f mins after",  _nightAlarmDelaySlider.value];











                _dawnSnoozeIntervalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f mins",  _dawnSnoozeIntervalSlider.value];
                _noonSnoozeIntervalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f mins",  _noonSnoozeIntervalSlider.value];
                _afternoonSnoozeIntervalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f mins",  _afternoonSnoozeIntervalSlider.value];
                _sunsetSnoozeIntervalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f mins",  _sunsetSnoozeIntervalSlider.value];
                _nightSnoozeIntervalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f mins",  _nightSnoozeIntervalSlider.value];

        }
             //  CFShow((__bridge CFTypeRef)(settingsDict));

    }

-(void)createSettings{
    settingsDict =   [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"showArabicQuranSwitch",
                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], @"showArabicQuranSwitch",

                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"dawnAlarmSwitch",
                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], @"sunriseAlarmSwitch",
                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"noonAlarmSwitch",
                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"afternoonAlarmSwitch",
                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"sunsetAlarmSwitch",
                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"nightAlarmSwitch",


                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:10], @"dawnSnoozeIntervalSlider",
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:10], @"noonSnoozeIntervalSlider",
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:10], @"afternoonSnoozeIntervalSlider",
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:10], @"sunsetSnoozeIntervalSlider",
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:10], @"nightSnoozeIntervalSlider",


                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"dawnAlarmDelaySlider",
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"noonAlarmDelaySlider",
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"afternoonAlarmDelaySlider",
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"sunsetAlarmDelaySlider",
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"nightAlarmDelaySlider",


                      nil];


    settingsData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:settingsDict];

    [defaults setObject:settingsData forKey:(NSString *)@"SettingsKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide code so we can try and help?

Comment: Could you go into more detail about the desired functionality? Also, a code snippet of when you are saving to/ reading from the NSUserDefaults could be helpful. One possibility to comes to mind is that you are not calling "synchronize", and some data is lost when there is an increase in memory pressure or the app closes before the data is save to the user defaults.

Comment: How do you know its not saving?

Comment: edited my comment to include my code. Please note that I am also calling synchronize and the code works perfectly in simulator and had been working for the device in the past

Comment: I know its not saving because when I retrieving the settings Dictionary for the key, I get nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this line

```
if (!settingsData)
    [self createSettings];
```

to

```
 settingsDict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:settingsData];

if (!settingsData || !settingsDict)
            [self createSettings];
```

and everything worked.